# Looking for books for trigonometric identities proofs

Tags: trigonometry, book-recommendation

I'm searching for a book that provides a "bank" for "complete" proofs for trigonometric identities. More specifically, I'm talking about identities such as:

```
Arctan(a)+Arctan(b)=Arctan((a+b)/(1-a.b))

Tan(a+b)=(tan(a)+tan(b))/(1-tan(a).tan(b))

Cos^2=1/(1+tan^2)

....
```

The closest thing that I found was ["trig or treat"](https://www.amazon.in/Trig-Treat-Encyclopedia-Trigonometric-Intellectually/dp/9812776192) by Adrian Ning Hong Yeo , but it doesn't contain all the basic proofs, and worse, it doesn't define the initial characteristics of the variables, such as which sets they belong to; it also has a "chill" approach, whereas I'm looking for something much more formal and canonical.

Comment: You may check "Trigonometry Essentials Practice Workbook" & other texts by "Chris McMullen" !!

Comment: @Prem, I checked the book you mentioned above, it's...a workbook....very non-canonical, definitely not intended to be a "bank" of proofs, and doesn't have proofs for all the basic identities, ex. the one containing the arctan that I mentioned in the post.... Thanks anyways for the suggestion...

Comment: Though that is not a real text book , there is a wiki list of Trigonometric Identities.